# SQL condition sum from two joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have two tables as below:

**Invoice**

```
InvId | Amount  | Name
-----------------------
1     | 50      | John
2     | 30      | Mike
3     | 20      | John
```

**Detail**

```
MetalType| Weight | InvId
-------------------------
Gold     | 2      | 2
Silver   | 4      | 3
Silver   | 3      | 3
Gold     | 5      | 1
```

I would like to have the following output, but my query will only provide the total for silver and gold for John. How can I build a query that will also include the total invoice amount for John.

Total Invoice Amount For John = **70**
Total Silver Weight  = **7**
total Gold Weith = **5**

```
SELECT
SUM(IFF(D.MetalType=”Gold”, D.Weight, 0)) AS TotGold,
SUM((IFF(D.MetalType=”Silver”, D.Weight, 0)) AS TotSilver
FROM Invoice I INNER JOIN Detail D ON I.InvId = D.InvId WHERE I.Name = “John”
```

Comment: @JohnWoo : because there is 2 different people: John and Mike, and the first entry in Detail is part of the 2. Invoice and it is not for John but Mike. So John has only 5 gold and 3 + 4 silver, and Mike has 2 Gold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

For Sql-Server:

```
SELECT 
SUM(TotalAmount) AS TotalAmount,
SUM(TotGold) AS TotGold,
SUM(TotSilver) AS TotSilver
FROM(
SELECT
SUM (I.Amount) OVER (Partition by D.Invid) AS TotalAmount,
SUM(CASE WHEN D.MetalType='Gold' THEN D.Weight ELSE 0 END) AS TotGold,
SUM(CASE WHEN D.MetalType='Silver' THEN D.Weight ELSE 0 END) AS TotSilver
FROM Invoice I INNER JOIN Detail D ON I.InvId = D.InvId

WHERE I.Name = 'John'
GROUP BY D.InvId, I.Amount) n
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4d2f/14)  - now it kills the duplicate detail and counts it only once.

EDITED for Access:

```
SELECT
  n.Name,
  MAX(TotalAmount),
  SUM(TotGold) AS TotGold,
  SUM(TotSilver) AS TotSilver
FROM(
  SELECT
   I.Name,
   SUM(CASE WHEN D.MetalType='Gold' THEN D.Weight ELSE 0 END) AS TotGold,
   SUM(CASE WHEN D.MetalType='Silver' THEN D.Weight ELSE 0 END) AS TotSilver
  FROM Invoice I 
  INNER JOIN Detail D ON I.InvId = D.InvId
  GROUP BY I.Name, D.InvId, I.Amount) n
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT
     I.Name, SUM (I.Amount) AS TotalAmount
    FROM Invoice I
    GROUP BY I.Name) m ON m.Name = n.Name
GROUP BY n.Name
```

Comment: Your solution works with MS SQL Server, but I am using MS Access. Is there another way you can build a query without using "Over (Partition by D.Invid)." Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but you defined the SQL-Server to your question. I update it to Access

Comment: Thank-you Sir, You must be a SQL guru, how about if I want the total amount for all the invoices, total weight of Gold, and total weight of silver.

Comment: If You mean, that for all customer not just for John, then here is an example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4d2f/44

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
With tbl3 (Amt,Gold,Silver)
as
(
    SELECT
    SUM (I.Amount) OVER (Partition by D.Invid) AS TotalAmount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.MetalType='Gold' THEN D.Weight ELSE 0 END) AS TotGold,
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.MetalType='Silver' THEN D.Weight ELSE 0 END) AS TotSilver
    FROM Invoice I Right JOIN Detail D ON I.InvId = D.InvId 
    WHERE I.Name = 'John' Group by D.InvId, I.Amount
)
Select SUM(Amt) as Total_Invoice_Amount_For_John,
SUM(Gold) as Total_Silver_Weight,
SUM(Silver) as Total_Gold_Width from tbl3
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e315/37)**

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried out the other queries already posted and they might already be suitable for what you want but here's my take on it :-

```
SELECT X.NAME, X.METALTYPE, X.WEIGHT, Y.TOTAL
FROM
    (SELECT NAME, METALTYPE, SUM(Weight) AS WEIGHT
    FROM INVOICE i
    INNER JOIN DETAIL d ON i.InvId = d.InvId
    GROUP BY NAME, METALTYPE) X
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS Total, NAME
    FROM INVOICE
    GROUP BY NAME)Y
    ON X.NAME = Y.NAME
ORDER BY NAME, TOTAL, METALTYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

select name, sum(Amount) as 'total invoice',sum(Gold) as 'Gold',sum(Silver) as Silver from(
select aa.Name,aa.Amount,
sum(case when bb.MetalType='Gold' then bb.Weight else 0 end) as 'Gold',
sum(case when bb.MetalType='Silver' then bb.Weight else 0 end) as 'Silver'
 from a  aa left outer join b bb on aa.InvID=bb.InvID group by aa.InvID) as c group by c.name